# Check if index !== last index inside forEach

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if my forEach loop is not at the last index so I can separate the numbers with commas. Currently it still uses a comma on the last number which I don't want.

```
const repeatNums = function(data) {
    let ans = '';
    data.forEach(function(item, index, arrsy) {
        ans += item[0].toString().repeat(item[1]);
        if (index !== -1) {
            ans += ', '
        }
    });
    return ans;
};
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.join`....`repeatNums = data.map(([one, two]) => one.toString().repeat(two)).join(',');`

Comment: What about using a basic for loop, it's then easy to mess with the iterator `if (i - 1 !== i)`.

Comment: @NVRM you mean like `while(i--) { }`?

Comment: @Jared Same same.. come on!

Comment: Do any of the answers help?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `map` and then `join` instead, which handles that for you.

```
return data.map(([first,second])=>first.toString().repeat(second)).join(', ');
```

Your current code is wrong because the index can never be negative; the last index of the array is one less than its length, as arrays are zero-indexed.

```
data.forEach(function(item, index, array){
    ans += item[0].toString().repeat(item[1]);
    if(index !== array.length - 1){
        ans += ', '
    }
});
```

Comment: A lot cleaner with destructuring per my comment above: `repeatNums = data.map(([one, two]) => one.toString().repeat(two)).join(',');`

Comment: @JaredSmith Agreed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the `index` argument in the loop to see if it is one less than `arrsy.length`.

Or, you could just use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
let ary = ["A","B","C","D"];
console.log(ary.join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

let joined = arr.join(', ');

console.log(joined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your function like this:

```
const repeatNums = function(data) {
    let ans = '';
    data.forEach(function(item, index, arrsy) {
        ans += item[0].toString().repeat(item[1]);
        if (index !== arrsy.length -1) {
            ans += ', '
        }
    });
    return ans;
};
```